# Does Bower expose download statistics for each package?

Tags: bower

Given a Bower package, I want to know how often people have installed it using Bower. Is that posible?

**P.S.** All that I found is a list of most populars packages and
 [ratings](http://bower.io/stats/).

**P.S.S.** I know, that, for example, npm, provides kind of downloads stats ([see it](http://img.shields.io/npm/dm/gulp-concat-css.svg) for a [gulp-concat-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat-css)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EDIT: The registry API no longer provides the number of hits per package.

The Bower registry keeps the number of "hits" per package which is actually the number of times a GET request for this package was sent to the registry. Since the Bower registry is only providing metadata (package lookup) and the downloads are done from somewhere else (Github), the number of hits does not reflect the actual number of download.
You can get the number of hits for a certain package by calling the registry API, for example: `https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery`

In additions Bower is collecting usage statistics from the Bower CLI. Stats are collected using Google analytics and are the source of what you see in http://bower.io/stats/.
Currently you can see the stats for the top packages but it seems that there are plans to allow getting stats per package. Take a look at Bower [issue 1164](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1164) and the Bower stats Github [repo](https://github.com/bower/stats) for more info.

Comment: `https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery` doesn't return anything related to hits anymore.